# Disable flash mode and wipe in recovery- mangmenet api

Tags: android, mobile, google-api, android-management-api

I'm using [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management), and I see if wipe data off ["factoryResetDisabled": true]- but can flash phone (and in Samsung devices can unlock bootloader and wipe data) and wipe data in recovery.

1. can disable wipe data and flash and download mode/fastboot?
2. have any way to know if the device not active? The mean device was to wipe data in recovery.
3. How do you set up phone auto after wiping data without scan qr code?
4. can set the device to download some of my company app (apk) not from google play? from my server...
5. can set qr code to setup the device language?
6. can set another default wallpaper to my specific wallpaper?

Google Management Api man say factoryResetDisabled": true - but its only for setting
for more i try see in google but not see more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your questions about the Android Management API and device management capabilities, I can provide some insights:

1. Disabling data wipe and flashing: You can use the [DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_DISABLED](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#:%7E:text=Defaults%20to%20DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_DISABLED.-,DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_DISABLED,-Default.%20Disables%20all) policy to disable developer settings on Android devices through the Android Management API. When this policy is applied, it prevents users from accessing and modifying developer settings, which includes features like bootloader unlocking, flashing, and accessing download mode/fastboot.
2. Determining device activity: You could use "lastStatusReportTime"  "lastPolicyComplianceReportTime"  "lastPolicySyncTime" from  [enterprises.devices.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) method to retrieve some information about the device activity.
3. Setting up a device automatically after data wipe: If you're looking for an automated device setup process without the need to scan a QR code you can utilize [Zero-Touch enrollment](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#zero-touch_enrollment). With Zero-Touch enrollment, devices are automatically enrolled into your organization's Android Enterprise account as soon as they are powered on and connected to the internet. This eliminates the need for manual configuration or scanning QR codes during the initial setup. But note that only devices purchased from authorized Zero-Touch resellers are eligible for this feature.
4. Installing apps from a server: The Android Management API allows you
   to distribute apps from the Google Play Store.  If you’d like to
   host the APKs on your infrastructure you can take a look at how to
   deploy [externally hosted apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145182?hl=en). The app assignment is done via
   Managed Google Play, however the devices will download the app from
   your infrastructure.
5. Setting device language via QR code: You can use the [QR code bundle](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#example_qr_code_bundle) in the Android Management API to configure the device language. Simply include the [EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCALE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCALE) parameter with the desired language code in the bundle. It is important to ensure that the language code is compatible with the device's operating system version and supported by the manufacturer.
6. Setting a custom default wallpaper: Currently, the Android Management API does not offer this feature.